# How can I query Django models with complex group-by query?

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-queryset

Assume that I have the following Django class:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()
    created_ts = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "<%s %s>" % (
            self.__class__.__name__,
            "; ".join(
                [
                    "ID: %s" % self.pk,
                    "a: %s" % self.a,
                    "created_ts: %s" % self.created_ts,
                ]
            )
        )
```

I would like to find the instances of `MyModel` with the latest `created_ts` for each distinct value of `a`. Can I do so with a single QuerySet? If so, what is that QuerySet? If not, what is the most efficient way to get that result?

In the end, I want to have Integer/MyModel-Instance pairs. The answer should look something approximately like this:

```
{
    1: <MyModel ID: 1; a: 1; created_ts: 2004-11-08 06:01:00>,
    5: <MyModel ID: 2; a: 5; created_ts: 2004-11-05 08:01:32>,
    3: <MyModel ID: 3; a: 3; created_ts: 2004-11-04 11:01:42>,
    0: <MyModel ID: 4; a: 0; created_ts: 2004-11-03 06:12:10>,
}
```

Comment: a is a foreignkey to another model?

Comment: No, `a` is an Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't do that in one query if you need the results to be `MyModel` objects, but you could get field `a` and latest `create_ts` together with django queryset [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values) method:

`MyModel.objects.values('a').annotate(latest_date=Max('create_ts'))`